# mysql workbench - Create a new schema and import tables and structures from existing schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an existing mysql schema with 10 tables (SCHEMA1). I need to create another schema (SCHEMA2) using the structures of the existing (SCHEMA1). I don't need the data just the structure.

So how do I get the existing 10 tables in the new schema ((SCHEMA2) using mysql workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the individual table and look at its details. Then go to the tab with the label DDL and just copy those `CREATE TABLE` statements to your new database. This will just create the tables and structure and then you are free to populate your table as you wish.

The top with the tabs (depending on your version) should look like this:

[image]

You should click on the last part over and then look at the table declaration inside.

Comment: So I go to the tables in SCHEMA1 , choose a table and then select table inspector. Then what?.

Comment: Edited to make it easier for you.

Comment: I have all of the tabs except DDL

Comment: No problem, best of luck with the rest of your coding.